# date_trunc at time zone with original timestamptz

Tags: postgresql

I have a single `timestamptz` that I want to `date_trunc` so it removes the hours:

`2019-01-01T17:43-03` => `2019-01-01T00:00-03`.

However, because `date_trunc` removes the timezone, I need to do it like this:

```
date_trunc('day', '2019-01-01T17:43-03'::timestamptz) at time zone '-03'
```

However, I do not want to hardcode the time zone, since the query is run with timestamptz in many different timezones (these are input to the query and not stored). So I want the timezone to be extracted from the original timestamp. I tried to do something like this, but it does not work:

```
date_trunc('day', '2019-01-01T17:43-03'::timestamptz) at time zone EXTRACT(...)
```

Related, I am trying to extract the timezone from a timestamptz, but just getting `0`.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(timezone FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2019-01-01T00:00+03')
0
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have a misconception about how timestamps and timezones are stored in PostgreSQL (because you seem to expect the `-03` to be preserved when calling `date_trunc` and that you "want the timezone to be extracted from the original timestamp").  According to [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html):

> When a timestamp with time zone value is output, it is always converted from UTC to the current timezone zone, and displayed as local time in that zone. To see the time in another time zone, either change timezone or use the AT TIME ZONE construct (see Section 9.9.3).

Therefore, the statement that "different clients [that] have timestampts in many different timezones," while true, are all translated to UTC for storage, and then displayed in your local timezone (or the timezone you specify) for output.  As such, calling `date_trunc()` will essentially truncate the UTC timestamp, and if you want it displayed in a specific timezone, you will need to add the `AT TIME ZONE` clause.

UPDATE: An example is here:

```
edb=# select date_trunc('day', '2019-01-01T17:43-03'::timestamptz) ;
       date_trunc       
------------------------
 2019-01-01 00:00:00+00
(1 row)

edb=# set timezone to 'US/Pacific';
SET
edb=# select date_trunc('day', '2019-01-01T17:43-03'::timestamptz) ;
       date_trunc       
------------------------
 2019-01-01 00:00:00-08
(1 row)
```

As you can see, `date_trunc` will append the timezone that I define—it is not omitted.

Comment: Thanks, but I do know this. The timestamp is not stored in postgres, but is an input to the query. My question is *how* do I add the `AT TIME ZONE` back to the trunced timestamptz with its original timezone when I cannot hardcode the timezone. `date_trunc` makes it lose its timezone. How do I bring it back, given that I have inputs with different timezones?

Comment: I've updated my post with an example--could you do likewise with your original question? Seems I'm not fully understanding, and need to see what you're seeing